# Savings Calculator GUI

Tags: java, user-interface, calculator

Having problem with my create button method.  Compiles/runs ok, but when attempt to calculate, I get the following error: "LoanFrame$1CalcListener.actionPerformed(LoanFrame.java:60)" which is my annualR doubleparse code.  Any reasons why this is giving me error, and ways to fix it?

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


public class LoanFrame extends JFrame {



private static final int FRAME_WIDTH = 650;
private static final int FRAME_LENGTH = 300;
private static final double INITIAL_BALANCE = 0.0;
private static final double ANNUAL_RATE = 0.0;
private static final int YEARS = 0;

String[] result;
private JLabel initialLabel;
private JLabel rate;
private JLabel years;
private JTextField initialBal;
private JTextField annualRate;
private JTextField numOfYears;
private JButton calculate;
private JPanel panel;
private JList box;
private JScrollPane scroll;


 LoanFrame(){
    createTextField();
    createButton();
    createScrollPane();
    createPanel();
    setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_LENGTH);
}   

private void createTextField(){
    final int FIELD_WIDTH = 10;
    initialLabel = new JLabel("Initial Balance");
    initialBal = new JTextField(FIELD_WIDTH);
    rate = new JLabel("Annual Rate");
    annualRate = new JTextField(FIELD_WIDTH);
    years = new JLabel("Number of Years");
    numOfYears = new JTextField(FIELD_WIDTH);
}
private void createButton(){
      calculate = new JButton("Calculate");
      class CalcListener implements ActionListener
      {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
         {
            double initialB = Double.parseDouble(initialBal.getText());
            double annualR = Double.parseDouble(rate.getText());
            int y = Integer.parseInt(years.getText());
            annualR = annualR / 100;

            for (int i = 0; i < y; i++) {
                double newbalance = initialB * annualR;
                initialB += newbalance;
                String test = String.valueOf(initialB);
                result[i] = test;
            }
            box = new JList(result);
            scroll = new JScrollPane(box);
            getContentPane().add(scroll);
         }            
      }
      ActionListener d = new CalcListener();
      calculate.addActionListener(d);
}
private void createScrollPane(){
    scroll = new JScrollPane();
}
private void createPanel()
   {
      panel = new JPanel();
      panel = new JPanel();
      panel.add(initialLabel);
      panel.add(initialBal);
      panel.add(rate);
      panel.add(annualRate);
      panel.add(years);
      panel.add(numOfYears);
      panel.add(calculate);
      panel.add(scroll);
      add(panel);
   }
}
```

EDIT: thanks for the replies, my error(After fixing double parse to (annualRate.getText)

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Number of Years"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at LoanFrame$1CalcListener.actionPerformed(LoanFrame.java:61)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: What is the text of the error message and/or type of error, what you posted is just the line of code that the exception occurred on.

Comment: As jzd said, hard to answer without knowing what the actual error is. Generally, I'd guess that, if you're getting an exception with Double#parseDouble, it is either because the text is not a number (meaning not a parsable double value), or the `getText()` method is returning null.

Comment: Thanks, added the list of errors.

Answer (score 4):

You're reading from the `JLabel` rather than the `JTextField`

```
double annualR = Double.parseDouble(rate.getText());
```

should be

```
double annualR = Double.parseDouble(annualRate.getText());
```

Comment: Nice, very observant.

Comment: No problem, you realize the same applys to `years` and `numOfYears`?

Comment: No did not realize it.  I'm just going to fix up my coding a bit.

Answer (score 1):

You get a `NullPointerException` at this line:

```
for (int i = 0; i < y; i++) {           
    double newbalance = initialB * annualR;
    initialB += newbalance;
    String test = String.valueOf(initialB);
    result[i] = test; // <-- NPE here
}
```

Because `result` has never been initialized.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, will be sure to do that.

Answer (score 0):

> I get the following error:
>   "LoanFrame$1CalcListener.actionPerformed(LoanFrame.java:60)" which is
>   my annualR doubleparse code

The text for `rate.getText()` is invalid format.

Comment: thanks for the reply.  Yeah I need to fix that part and examine my code more closely